# ArangoDB: user authentication in web console not working

Tags: authentication, arangodb, web-console

I am setting up a new ArangoDB cluster on Windows, and for some reason it is not asking for credentials when I hit the web interface on :8529. Arangosh requires credentials, but not the web portion. Otherwise the cluster behaves exactly how I would expect.

I am running v3.11.1 on all three servers, and here is the command I am using to start the cluster on each server. I have added line breaks to make it easier to read; it is all on a single line when I execute it.

```
"c:\my\path\arangodb.exe" --starter.mode=cluster \
--starter.join=server1:8528,server2:8528,server3:8528 \
--args.all.server.statistics=true \
--args.all.server.jwt-secret-keyfile=c:\my\path\pkidb.jwt \
--args.all.log.time-format=utc-datestring-millis \
--args.all.log.role=true \
--args.all.log.hostname=auto \
--args.all.log.use-json-format=true \
--args.all.log.output=c:\my\path\log\arangodb.json \
--ssl.keyfile=c:\my\path\arangodb.pem \
--args.all.ssl.protocol=9 \
--args.all.ssl.session-cache=true \
--args.all.ssl.cipher-list=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I have created users in the web console ("user1" for example), and I have user1 assigned as the database owner and administrator. I have a cluster setup using an older version and user authentication at the web console works fine. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I checked the current documentation and it seems as though user authentication is enabled by default. I tried explicitly enabling authentication by adding this to the command shown above, but arangodb.exe did not care for the `server.authentication` option, and `server.authentication-system-only` by itself did not seem to make a difference.

```
--args.all.server.authentication true --args.all.server.authentication-system-only false
```